# CTRL + Space does not work as it suppose to work on eclipse macbook

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to buil a project on Eclipse Java but having a issue about using shortcuts. I am trying to use ctrl + space combination for system.out.println but it does not work. I tried almost everything on internet but still could not solve it. It gives a method option about sysout but that is not what i want obviously. I was using eclipse on windows so have no clue how can i solve it. Searched it but none of them worked. Here are what i tried and settings of my eclipse and mac:

[I checked Template Proposals, it did not work. Click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzOLb.jpg)

[I disabled input shortcuts for keyboard, it did not work. Click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkPIh.png)

[I unchecked use default formatter but it also did not work. Click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2XYl.jpg)

[This is what happens when i use ctrl+space. Click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRT0g.png)

I am using macOS Big Sur 11.6.4

Comment: Is this the latest Eclipse release, 2022-03/4.23?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the "Auto activation delay (ms) to 1ms at Window/Preferences/Java/Editor/Content Assist.

[image: Image to help :)]

Comment: I had the same issue with 2022-09.  I fixed it by going to Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates and edited the Context from "Java statements" to "Java".